# Python Idle 3.8.8 vs Python Terminal 3.8.8 round() format issue?

Tags: python, python-3.8

When running the following code in my application using the terminal and **Python 3.8.8 (Anaconda and VSC)**:

```
def test():
    print(round(random.uniform(7, 10), 2))

test()
```

...I'm returning multiple decimals places rather than the two decimal places defined in round(), and the length is always different:

7.1234567890 *# for example*

8.1234 *# for example*

9.012345 *# for example*

When I run the same code block in **Idle 3.8.8**, the function returns exactly what is expected, a return value with exactly two decimal places - every time.

Does anyone know why this would be and more importantly, how I can force two decimal places as a return value in the terminal?

---**ADDED ORIGINAL CODE**---

```
# ____NPC Damage____ 
if npc_race == npc_races[0]: # Troll
    npc_race_atk_pwr = round(random.uniform(7, 10), 2)

# NPC Weapons Class
npc_1h_wpns = ["Hammer"]#, "Polearm", "Sword", "Spell"
npc_1h_wpn = random.choice(npc_1h_wpns)

npc_2h_wpns = ["Polearm"]#, "Shield", "Sword"
npc_2h_wpn = random.choice(npc_2h_wpns)

npc_cls_wpns = [npc_1h_wpn, npc_2h_wpn]
npc_cls_wpn = random.choice(npc_cls_wpns)

# NPC Weapon Damage
if npc_race == npc_races[0]: # Troll
    if npc_cls_wpn == npc_1h_wpns[0]: # One-Handed Hammer
        npc_cls_wpn_dmg = round(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5), 2)
    elif npc_cls_wpn == npc_2h_wpns[0]: # Polearm
        npc_cls_wpn_dmg = round(random.uniform(0.1, 0.6), 2)

# NPC Critical Weapon Damage
npc_cls_wpn_crt = random.randint(1, 5) # creates the chance for a critical hit
if npc_cls_wpn_crt == 3:
    npc_cls_wpn_crt_dmg = round(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3), 2)


if npc_race == npc_races[0]: # Troll
    print(f"A {npc_race} was selected for battle. The {str.lower(npc_race)} is using a {str.lower(npc_cls_wpn)} as its weapon and has {npc_hlth}% health. Do you want to fight? ")

fight_confirmation = input("Enter Y/N: ")

if fight_confirmation == "Y" or fight_confirmation == "y":
    if npc_race == npc_races[0]: # Troll
        total_wpn_dmg = npc_race_atk_pwr * npc_cls_wpn_dmg
        total_wpn_dmg += npc_race_atk_pwr

        plyr_cur_hlth = plyr_hlth - total_wpn_dmg     

    print(f"\n\nThe {npc_race} has attacked you with {total_wpn_dmg} weapon damage.")

    if npc_cls_wpn_crt == 3:
        total_wpn_crt_dmg = npc_cls_wpn_crt_dmg * total_wpn_dmg
        total_wpn_dmg += total_wpn_crt_dmg
        print(f"You've been critically hit for an additional {total_wpn_crt_dmg} damage resulting in {total_wpn_dmg} total damage!")

        plyr_cur_hlth = plyr_cur_hlth - total_wpn_crt_dmg

    print(f"\n\nYour health has decreased to {plyr_cur_hlth}%.\n\n\n")
```

No other number-related variables other than what is defined here are stored, other than plyr_hlth = 100.

---**EXAMPLE OF THE OUTPUT**---

```
A Troll was selected for battle. The troll is using a hammer as its weapon and has 62% health. Do you want to fight? 
Enter Y/N: y

The Troll has attacked you with 8.2038 weapon damage.
You've been critically hit for an additional 1.886874 damage resulting in 10.090674 total damage!


Your health has decreased to 89.909326%.


# printed out values of variables for verification
npc_cls_wpn_dmg 0.13 
npc_race_atk_pwr 7.26
npc_cls_wpn_crt_dmg 0.23
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't believe you.  You must have been running two different sets of code.

Comment: Instead of your constructed examples, show us some real live values!

Comment: @Tim I mentioned it was run inside the application code. Updated.

Comment: The code you show does various mathematical operations on your numbers, like `total_wpn_dmg += npc_race_atk_pwr` and `total_wpn_crt_dmg = npc_cls_wpn_crt_dmg * total_wpn_dmg`. That can change the number of digits in the number's string representation. Are you sure the numbers you're seeing with more digits are the originally generated ones, not ones after these operations?

Comment: @Blckknght yes, I've printed the values out and all of the variables have the return values containing two decimal places. I'm going to keep working through this.

Comment: Here is some sage advice about floating point numbers.  Don't worry about KEEPING the numbers at two decimal places.  Keep them all internally with their full precision.  Only do the rounding when you need to PRINT the values.  Remember, it's only the human who cares about the number of decimal places.  Any arithmetic you do will add more decimal places, and they're all just approximations anyway.

Comment: I believe I found the issue, it is an operations error. It was with multiplication of the initial total_wpn_dmg variable.

Tim, thanks for the advice, that seems much more logical and will do that going forward. I'm very new to programming and making tons of mistakes, however, each one is a learning opportunity and this time I learned a way to resolve logical errors, and of course your tip! Thanks ladies/gentlemen.